# Formatar Data em javascript para "daqui a Xd Yh zm"

Tags: javascript, datetime

Amigos, estou tentando formatar uma data em javascript para ficar no seguinte formato:

Daqui a x Dias, y Horas, Z minutos.

Só que o meu código não está funcionando corretamente:

```
dt = dados[i].Hora - dataAtual; // o valor está em segundos

todos_min = Math.round(dt/60);

min_restantes = Math.round(todos_min%60);

todas_hrs = Math.round(todos_min/60);

hrs_restantes = Math.round(todas_hrs%24);

todos_dias = Math.round(todas_hrs/24);
console.log( todos_dias+'d '+hrs_restantes+'h '+min_restantes+'m' );
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: Seu código está funcionando normalmente amigo, poderia descrever melhor seu erro?

Comment: O código não possui erros de execução, mas notei alguns problemas de lógica. Sei que este tipo de desatenção acontece, então detalhei bastante minha resposta *não* por achar que você precisa, mas principalmente para auxiliar outras pessoas que venham a ter o mesmo problema durante sua fase de estudos de programação :D espero que ajude! Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, vou tentar ser o mais didático possível, para que mais pessoas possam tirar proveito desta resposta no futuro.

Apesar de que você PODE começar selecionando os minutos, depois as horas e depois os dias, geralmente é mais fácil fazer da maneira inversa. O diagrama mostra a ideia geral de como transformar de uma unidade menor (no seu caso, *segundos*) para unidades maiores (no seu caso, *minutos*, *horas* e *dias*).

[image: Rascunho: convertendo um valor (em uma unidade pequena) para unidades maiores.]

A ideia é que, com a entrada medida na menor unidade (*segundos*), o algoritmo encontre num 1º passo quantas vezes a maior unidade (*dias*) cabe dentro dessa entrada -- no diagrama, são 3 vezes. Então, no 2º passo, o programa encontrará quantas vezes a segunda maior unidade (*horas*) cabe dentro do **resto** do 1º passo, e assim sucessivamente até que a precisão desejada seja atingida.

Uma implementação deste algoritmo encontra-se [neste jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h82Q/1/), com vários comentários para auxiliar o entendimento.

Dois detalhes perigosos que notei no seu código foram:

- **Math.round()**: arredonda para o valor inteiro mais próximo, seja ele *maior* ou *menor*. Por exemplo: 1,5 e 1,598 e seriam arredondados para 2; já 1,499 e 1,0 seriam arredondados para 1. Por isso, achei perigoso o uso desta função, pois, para eliminar os excedentes em cada etapa, não queremos que o algoritmo arredonde para cima em nenhum caso. Sugiro a utilização da *Math.floor()*, que sempre arredonda para baixo.
- Apesar de você descobrir quantos minutos restam, você **utiliza o total de minutos para obter as horas**, e a mesma coisa se **repete para as horas em relação aos dias**. Suponha, por exemplo, que o total de horas é 15 (`todas_hrs=15`). De acordo com seu algoritmo, as horas restantes (`hrs_restantes = Math.round(todas_hrs%24)`) seriam 15 (o que está correto), porém o número de dias (`todos_dias = Math.round(todas_hrs/24)`) seria igual a `Math.round(15/24)` que resulta em... 1!!!

Ajustando esses detalhes, você vai perceber que não é *impossível* fazer do seu método, mas precisa de mais atenção, motivo pelo qual recomendo o uso do algoritmo mais popular, que eu indiquei, ok?

Espero ter ajudado! Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Faça um arquivo .html com esse codigo

Seu codigo está funcionando normalmente.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>    

   dt = 86400; //1d 0h 0s o valor está em segundos

   todos_min = Math.round(dt/60);

   min_restantes = Math.round(todos_min%60);

   todas_hrs = Math.round(todos_min/60);

   hrs_restantes = Math.round(todas_hrs%24);

   todos_dias = Math.round(todas_hrs/24);

   document.write( todos_dias+'d '+hrs_restantes+'h '+min_restantes+'m' );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```